# Android Launcher2 source code importing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can someone sort out a solution to the problem of importing and recompile Launcher2 to eclipse. The 5 errors are as :

1. DISALLOW_MODIFY_ACCOUNTS cannot be resolved or is not a field
2. JELLY_BEAN_MR2 cannot be resolved or is not a field
3. Search cannot be resolved to a variable
4. The import com.android.common cannot be resolved
5. The method getUserRestrictions() is undefined for the type
   UserManager

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to compile the source code using wrong SDK version. You should use Android API Level 18.

Also you can find `com.android.common` sources in `$AOSP_FOLDER/frameworks/ex/common`.

Answer (score 0):

> **public static final int JELLY_BEAN_MR2** Added in API level 18 Android
>   4.3: Jelly Bean MR2, the revenge of the beans. Constant Value: 18 (0x00000012)

You must have defined at least API level 18, but you can still using the `minSdkVersion` just add as `targetSdkVersion` API level 18 in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

you can change it too in project properties -> Project Build Target. Change to API level 18 or higher!
[image]